# Valgrind prints summary with errors while application is running but says no leaks possible when finished

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, fork, valgrind, poco-libraries

I am trying to pinpoint memory errors of an application with valgrind.

Valgrind shows a strange behaviour that I haven't observed so far with it: Valgrind prints summary with errors while application is running but says all freed no leaks possible when finished

Unfortunately, I can not disclose the application source code behind it, but I can tell that

- the application is multi-threaded
- the application uses zmq
- the application is written in C++(11)
- the application is built with gcc-4.9.2
- runs on Debian: Debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux (from uname -a)
- I have downloaded valgrind 3.13.0 source snapshot and built it on same system with same compiler

Maybe someone has a hint or clue what happens here? I am uncertain if the program runs fine or not. When debugging or testing, I discover no problems with the application, i.e. also with gdb attached, the application performs a graceful shutdown.

Here's what happens:

```
valgrind ./<application>


==11431== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11431== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11431== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11431== Command: ./<<application>>
==11431== 

                     << output from application being analyzed >>

==11446== 
==11446== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11446==     in use at exit: 36,963,243 bytes in 12,456 blocks
==11446==   total heap usage: 112,306 allocs, 99,850 frees, 167,728,353 bytes allocated
==11446== 
==11446== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11446==    definitely lost: 13,419 bytes in 163 blocks
==11446==    indirectly lost: 24,368 bytes in 486 blocks
==11446==      possibly lost: 5,741 bytes in 106 blocks
==11446==    still reachable: 36,919,715 bytes in 11,701 blocks
==11446==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==11446==                         stdstring          : 211,119 bytes in 5,162 blocks
==11446==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11446== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11446== 
==11446== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11446== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==11448== 
==11448== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11448==     in use at exit: 37,699,870 bytes in 12,837 blocks
==11448==   total heap usage: 115,854 allocs, 103,017 frees, 168,950,644 bytes allocated
==11448== 
==11448== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11448==    definitely lost: 14,252 bytes in 155 blocks
==11448==    indirectly lost: 24,864 bytes in 498 blocks
==11448==      possibly lost: 5,749 bytes in 106 blocks
==11448==    still reachable: 37,655,005 bytes in 12,078 blocks
==11448==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==11448==                         stdstring          : 214,732 bytes in 5,238 blocks
==11448==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11448== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11448== 
==11448== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11448== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==11449== 
==11449== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11449==     in use at exit: 37,817,537 bytes in 12,875 blocks
==11449==   total heap usage: 119,125 allocs, 106,250 frees, 170,106,138 bytes allocated
==11449== 
==11449== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11449==    definitely lost: 12,013 bytes in 146 blocks
==11449==    indirectly lost: 24,864 bytes in 498 blocks
==11449==      possibly lost: 5,749 bytes in 106 blocks
==11449==    still reachable: 37,774,911 bytes in 12,125 blocks
==11449==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==11449==                         stdstring          : 215,361 bytes in 5,252 blocks
==11449==                         multipleinheritance: 992 bytes in 1 blocks
==11449==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11449== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11449== 
==11449== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11449== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

               << output from application being analyzed, app is shutting down now >>

==11431== 
==11431== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11431==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11431==   total heap usage: 343,376 allocs, 343,376 frees, 329,511,726 bytes allocated
==11431== 
==11431== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11431== 
==11431== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11431== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Maybe it's threads that leak memory, and main thread then summarized as last one and it's fine? Try the `--leak-check=full` flag, but be prepared for ton of output (looking at the number of leaks).

Comment: Yep, tried with --leak-check=full that's really a ton of output. However, final summary claims no leaks possible. The full output does not provide additional information for me, it just seems, that after that first event that causes (or causes not) a memory error, simply EVERY single new or malloc causes an error (the output runs down in my terminal for some minutes...).

I don't know where to start, honestly but I also don't want to waste time in hunting false positives...

Comment: I'm no expert in valgrind and have never used it with multithreaded applications, sorry. My best guess was above - it could summarize each thread separately. Maybe the threads are not joined before the application ends? It could explain large number of still reachable blocks. Have you tried hunting down one or two leaks (preferably from beginning of the list) to see if they really are false-positives? You can pipe your output to a file to check it easier after valgrind finishes.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, of course, thanks for that hint. I think you're right in the point that i have to hunt down at least the first one.. and pinpoint whether this could be a real error. However, I don't think valgrind puts a summary for each thread, because running valgrind with apps that use a similar threading design yields only one summary, and, there are much more threads running in the application than summaries are printed. Also, I don't think, I have an unjoined thread since that usually results in a std::terminate call on joinable threads and i can catch that with gdb.

Comment: Is your application using `fork` ? Valgrind might be printing one summary per subprocess.

Comment: @VincentSaulue-Laborde: hm, good point... it uses Poco::Process::launch(...) to control a system process.. haven't looked in the details of it but it might use fork... Will have a look at that, thanks

Answer (score 3):

@Vincent Saulue-Laborde, thanks you guided me to the right direction.

The double-summary results from a `fork` behind a `Poco::Process::launch` call.

Here's a minimal example - note that "route" is not available on this debian (but it is, when cross-compiling this application for the actual arm-target):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Process.h>
#include <Poco/Pipe.h>

int main()
{
    Poco::Pipe out_pipe;
    if (Poco::Process::launch("route", {}, 0, &out_pipe, 0).wait() == EXIT_SUCCESS) { }
    return 0;
}
```

running this with valgrind and adding switch --trace-children:

```
    valgrind --leak-check=full --trace-children=yes ./hello_world
==1814== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1814== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1814== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1814== Command: ./hello_world
==1814== 
==1815== 
==1815== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1815==     in use at exit: 10,612 bytes in 102 blocks
==1815==   total heap usage: 113 allocs, 11 frees, 13,028 bytes allocated
==1815== 
==1815== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 102
==1815==    at 0x4C28215: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==1815==    by 0x7B40147: Poco::ProcessImpl::launchByForkExecImpl(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string const&, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&) (in /home/user/dev/zedboard/build/deps/host/Debug/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60)
==1815==    by 0x7B41648: Poco::Process::launch(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*) (in /home/user/dev/zedboard/build/deps/host/Debug/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60)
==1815==    by 0x401E09: main (main.cpp:8)
==1815== 
==1815== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1815==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==1815==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1815==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1815==    still reachable: 10,596 bytes in 101 blocks
==1815==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==1815==                         stdstring          : 3,123 bytes in 87 blocks
==1815==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1815== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1815== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1815== 
==1815== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1815== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==1814== 
==1814== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1814==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1814==   total heap usage: 116 allocs, 116 frees, 13,837 bytes allocated
==1814== 
==1814== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1814== 
==1814== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1814== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

maybe I should file a bug for Poco...

Comment: The leaks might be false positives. You should rerun valgrind with `--trace-children=yes`, to properly intercept/handle `exec` calls. From [Valgrind docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html) : `This is necessary for multi-process programs`.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing reports of child processes. Each report has a process id between the equal signs. Which is different for the reports with memory leakage than for the final report.

When a child process is started but can't just vanish out of valgrind's view with executing the target executable then it must terminate. Unfortunately valgrind then prints a memory leak report with leaks that are not really preventable in the library code.

If possible a quite work-around is starting valgrind using `--child-silent-after-fork=yes` which simply silences all reporting from the forked child processes. This of course is only a valid option if no child process needs to be investigated for memory leakage.